# How to cast integer as tuple of bool

Tags: python

I have an integer, and would like to cast it as a tuple of boolean-likes— `{0, 1}` specifically. The way which comes to mind is `tuple(int(b) for b in bin(my_int)[2:])`, but feels off. What is the idiomatic/canonical way perform this?

Edit: for clarity, if the integer is `3`, the tuple would be `(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)`. To further clarify, assume the integer is in `{0, 1, …, 255}` and the tuple’s length should be eight. So what I have at this point (but aim to improve) is `tuple(int(b) for b in bin(my_int)[2:].zfill(8))`

Comment: `tuple(map(int, f"{my_int:b}"))`?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want to convert the integer to the binary representation as tuple?

Comment: What you propose is fine, unless you prefer map.  Python is a scripting language, it's going to look hacky doing stuff like this, becasue you're not supposed to work with bits (much).  Are you looking for [struct](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) ?

Comment: do you want a tuple or a set? {} means set, () is tuple. after pauls comment I have no idea what you want

Comment: Integers aren't 8 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think your way is bad, but I found another one:

```py
def to_binary(num):
    result = []
    while num >= 1:
        result.insert(0, num%2)
        num//=2
    return result
print(to_binary(5))
>>> [1, 0, 1]
```

Or you can add via append and at the end reverse via `[::-1]`. To be honest, I don't remember which is faster.

UPD [07.07.2022]

As I understand it, you need a tuple, and if its length is less than eight characters, you need to complement it with 0 on the left.

In this case, the code will change a little:

```py
def to_binary(num):
    result = []
    while num >= 1:
        result.insert(0, num%2)
        num//=2
    result =  tuple([0] * (max(8-len(result), 0)) + result)
    return result
```

Or you can also update your code by adding `zfill` method:

```py
your_tuple = tuple(int(b) for b in bin(3)[2:].zfill(8))
```

Comment: It doesn't matter which is faster.  Unless profiling proves it does.

Comment: Indeed. I just decided to clarify, suddenly for the one who asked this is important

Comment: Maybe make a list `[0]*8` first, then set the values starting from the right with a decrementing index (if that makes any sense)? Not sure if it's worth it but I'm curious.

Comment: @fsimonjetz, yes, your option is good, but what if we need more than 8 cells? (for example, for the number 2**8 you need 9 cells). Although in principle it can be processed...

Comment: @thebadgateway, did I answer your question?

Comment: to be honest, I don’t know what other solution you can come up with and it’s unlikely to turn out to be better